# How to fill two tables(one to many) within one method and add the foreign key automatically

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have two tables named `ot_req` and `transport`. If an employee wants to make an OT request with transport, I have to fill the `transport` table. `transport_id`(auto_increment) from the `transport` table is the foreign key of `ot_req` table. After filling the `transport` table I want to apply the auto incremented `transport_id` to the `ot_req` table. Is there any way to fill the data automatically?
I wrote the method like this, but it wont work for me.

```
public OTReqAddResponse OTReqAdd(OTReqAddRequest req)
    {
        OTReqAddResponse res = new OTReqAddResponse();
    using (var dbTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            ot_req objReq = new ot_req();
            transport objTransport = new transport();

            if (otDet.flag == 1)
            {
                  objTransport.form = req.from;
                  objTransport.to = req.to;
                  objTransport.destination = req.destination;
                  objTransport.reason = req.reason;

                  context.transports.Add(objTransport);
                  context.SaveChanges();

                  objOtReq.transport_id = objTransport.transport_id;
              }


            objReq.created_date = req.createdDate;
            objReq.creator = req.empId;
            objReq.status = 2;
            objReq.project_id = req.projectId;

            context.ot_req.Add(objReq);
            context.SaveChanges();

            dbTransaction.Commit();
          }

        dbTransaction.Dispose();
    }
    return res;
}
```

how can I retrieve the `tranport_id` from the mySql database and apply as a foreign key to the `ot_req` table at the same time with one commit?

Comment: try to get the insert_id while executing the query in MySQL.

Like `$conn->insert_id`

Comment: did you mark the transport_id property with a DatabaseGeneratedOption ?

Comment: Thank you guys. @vignesh's answer works for me.

Comment: What is `OTReqAddResponse `?  I think you should tell me what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***ot_req*** object should have a property that links back to the ***transport*** object. (It is maybe called transport? If I'm reading the navigation section below correctly.) If you set that property to your new, uncommitted transport object, it will automatically fill in the key when it commits both objects.

```
 ot_req objReq = new ot_req();
 // whatever

 transport transport = new transport();
 objReq.transport = transport ; // This will auto-fill the FK during commit.
 // whatever

 // Add both ot_req and transport to the context and commit.
 context.ot_req.Add(objReq);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this might help you to move forward!

Comment: @MansoorAbdullah glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

To Add linked entities you simply need to build up the parent object by adding the child then save the parent object, entity framework will sort out the foreign keys and save both objects.

e.g.

var children = new List<'Child'>();

children.Add(new Child());

var parent = new Parent { Children = children};

dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);

dbContext.SaveChanges();